# Where should a value used by a Laravel ViewComposer be stored

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to keep a value stored that can be applied to any instance of a particular view being included (and update that value each time it is included). The view is a partial, can be included many times across a page and used anywhere, and the value is just so I can apply a different CSS class to each one, as a simple example:

```
<div class="my-class-name-{{$variable}}">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

NOTE: This is not meant to be a unique identifier, for example if I had 3 variations of the CSS class `$variable` would only ever count to 3 then reset to 1 (repeating as required). This does mean I need to store a max value and a tiny bit of logic along side my variable.

So in searching I found a potential solution in the form of a ViewComposer, that can bind a variable every time a view is rendered - which seems perfect for this problem. Example:

**/app/Http/View/Composers/ViewComposer**

```
class ViewComposer
{

    //...

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('variable', $value);
    }
}
```

**/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider**

```
    // ...

    public function register()
    {
        View::composer(
            'newname', 'App\Http\View\Composers\ViewComposer'
        );
    }
```

Seems great, and if I ever want to make this more complicated, I can easily extend it in the ViewComposer.

So my question now becomes, **I need to store `$value` somewhere - but where is best practice?**

A model doesn't make sense to me, having a database table involved for a counter seems overkill. I could track it in a controller but having the `ViewComposer` talk directly to a controller strikes me as bad practice, and because this view could be included anywhere this value would need to basically exist in every controller and be passed to every view - seems messy.

A static property in the `ViewComposer` itself would work, and just `ViewComposer:$value++` on each call to compose, but is this a good place to store such a value? My only concern with using a static value in the ViewComposer is that, if this ever grew and I was passing multiple variables into this view, is it semantically appropriate to store such static values in a composer?

Above all else, **is this solution the best way to achieve what I am trying to do?**

Answer (score 0):

If the value doesn't need to persist between calls and you need to increment you could do it like:

```
class="my-class-name-{{$variable++}}"
...
```

If that number has a maximum that you know of, you could pass that other number through your ViewComposer and do it like:

```
class="my-class-name-{{$variable++ % $modulo}}"
...
```

If that value needs to persist between calls I would say that a singleton database table should be fine, specially considering that this functionality can be extended; you can just add a new column.

I think we may need a bit more of details to know which solution would be the best.